# Friedmann equations in a polar axial anisotropic universe

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astronomy, space-expansion

The first Friedmann equations which describes the expansion and content of the universe is as follows:

$$
H^2 = (\frac{\dot{a}}{a})^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{3} \rho - \frac{kc^2}{a^2} + \frac{\Lambda c^2}{3}
$$

and the derived Hubble parameter is:

$$
H_{0} = \sqrt{(\Omega_{c} + \Omega_{b})a^{-3} +\Omega_{rad}a^{-4} + \Omega_{k}a^{-2} + \Omega_{DE}a^{-3(1+w)} }
$$

However, these are based on the assumptions that the Universe is isotropic and homogeneous.

What if the universe has an axial polar anisotropy, how would Friedmann's equations be modified to account for this?

Comment: I don't know if it's been done, but I imagine you would have to start with modifying $\rm d\Sigma$ in the [spatial metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric#General_metric) and work from there.

Comment: @Pulsar Can you please attempt a reply? Thanks.